# How save XDocument to sql column type XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have column is type `XML`.

In dbml I get type this column is `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`

I have XDocument and I need save in column xml.

how do this?

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I tried! first search method in XDocument for translate to XElement. second I search in google and the third seems to me that this is not the case

Comment: I tried work with XmlWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XDocument.Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) property will return an `XElement` for the root element.